# How can I get a Dialog to display onclick in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-studio

I am currently developing an app for my post-secondary comp sci class. I am trying to display a Dialog popup box to the user after they click on a list view item. Eventually the finished product will contain various parking spots, however for right now it just contains text in the effort of trying to get the Dialog working.

I have tried a great deal of different things spanning ~4 hours. The furthest I got was the Dialog partially displaying when put into the FlatList itself. We are all VERY new to React Native, which is why I suspect I may have used something that is blocking my code.

Currently everything else works fine, and when I click on a Text element it successfully console logs that it is being used.
[image: Here is what the current view looks like, I know it looks like crap.]

Here is the code for the list:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { showToast } from '../utils/Toast';
import { Button, Dialog, Portal, Provider, PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';


/**
 * A list of parking spots of a selected parking zone
 * @param parkingSpotArray array containing the parking spots
 * @returns a list containing the parking spots
 */
const ParkingSpotList = ({parkingSpotArray}) => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);

    const ParkingSpotDialog = () => {
        return (
            <PaperProvider>
                <Portal>
                    <Dialog visible={visible} onDismiss={hideDialog}>
                        <Dialog.Title>Alert</Dialog.Title>
                        <Dialog.Content>
                            <Text variant="bodyMedium">This is a simple dialog</Text>
                        </Dialog.Content>
                    </Dialog>
                </Portal>
            </PaperProvider>
        );
    };

    const hideDialog = () => setVisible(false);

    const showDialog = () => {
        setVisible(true);
        console.log('showDialog');
    }

    const ParkingSpotListItem = ({item}) => (
        <View>
            <Text onPress={showDialog}>{item}</Text>
            // When I move the parking spot dialog here,
            // it works and I see a super small portion of the dialog.
            // but not enough of it...
        </View>
    )

    if(parkingSpotArray.length === 0)
    {
        showToast({message: 'No Parking Spots in this lot'})
    }

    return(
        <>
            <FlatList
            data={parkingSpotArray}
            renderItem={ParkingSpotListItem}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
            <ParkingSpotDialog></ParkingSpotDialog>
        </>
    );
};

export default ParkingSpotList;
```

And here is the code for the ListView:

```
import React from "react";
import {View, Button, StyleSheet} from "react-native"
import ParkingSpotList from "../components/ParkingSpotList"
// import {PaperProvider} from 'react-native-paper'

/**
 * A view that will display the parking spot list
 */
const ParkingSpotListView = () => {
    const data = "Hello, world"
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ParkingSpotList parkingSpotArray={data}/>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
});

export default ParkingSpotListView;
```

Please remember that I am very new at React Native and simply want to learn for the future since I have 4 months of this project developing ahead of me. Any help is very greatly appreciated!!

Comment: As i understand from your description you want a component to overlay your parent component and show some information in this component. React native modal can help you and you have full control on it's content.https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal